# How to combine JOIN and NOT EXISTS in a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I have three tables with their respective rows.

```
all_students     all_courses    courses_students
------------     -----------    ----------------
id               id             student_id (foreign key from all_students.id)
name             name           course_id (foreign key from all_courses.id)
```

When a student registers for a course, their id will be stored in courses_students table along with the course id. So far I can retrieve all the student names and their courses by using this query:

```
SELECT s.id    AS studentId,
       s.name  AS studentName,
       c.id    AS courseId,
       c.name  AS courseName,
FROM   courses_students AS cs
JOIN   all_students     AS s ON s.id = cs.student_id
JOIN   all_courses      AS c ON c.id = cs.course_id;
```

How do I modify the above query so that I can also show students who are not registered to any course?

Comment: what do you want to show as courseId/courseName for them?

Answer (score 3):

Use left joins instead of the (default) inner joins you query is currently using:

```
SELECT
    s.id AS studentId,
    s.name AS studentName,
    COALESCE(c.id, 'NA') AS courseId,
    COALESCE(c.name, 'NA') AS courseName
FROM all_students s
LEFT JOIN courses_students AS cs
    ON s.id = cs.student_id
LEFT JOIN all_courses AS c
    ON c.id = cs.course_id;
```

The key point here is to use left joins so that no students get dropped off should they not match any courses.  Also, we start the query with the `all_students` table, and join out from there.

Answer (score 2):

Change the student-to-studentcourses join to be a LEFT JOIN and look for nulls on the join column:

```
SELECT s.id    AS studentId,
   s.name  AS studentName,
   c.id    AS courseId,
   c.name  AS courseName,
FROM  
  all_students s 
  LEFT JOIN courses_students cs ON cs.student_id = s.id 
  LEFT JOIN all_courses c ON c.id = cs.course_id
WHERE cs.student_id IS NULL
```

A left join takes the table on the left side (the table mentioned before the word "join" - writing order is important and we tend to rearrange our queries to always use left join rather than use right join, because databases process joins in left to right order) as the solid table, whose rows must all be present in the output, and it tries to match rows from the right table to them. If it doesn't find a match, it gives up and puts all nulls for the table on the right instead of real data. His means the table on the right probably ends up with holes in the data where there was no match, hence why I think of the left side as "solid" and the right side as "patchy/sparse/hole-y"

```
s.id, cs.student_id
1     1
2     NULL
```

Student 1 has a match, student 2 does not (no rows in student courses had student ID 2)

Because cs.student_id is part of the join, the only way a NULL can be in this column is if the join didn't work out (no courses for that student).. if you were to use some other column from a table that is left joined it could work too, because all columns in a joined table are null if a left join fails to find a matching row, but other columns could naturally contain a null (like no one decided the classroom for a course yet so the data is just null) as part of the data, so by looking for nulls in the join column we can be sure we are only getting rows where the join didn't match. If we'd said "where courses.classroom is null" it would find students who didn't have a course, but there's a risk it would also find all students assigned to a course that didn't have a classroom set yet

Using EXISTS looks a little different, and you'd need to take out the joins because there isn't any point having them there/they will kill your results if there isn't a matching course:

```
SELECT *    
FROM all_students s 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT null FROM courses_students x WHERE x.student_id = s.id)
```

You could conceive that, for every row in students, your db will take the id, substitute it into the subquery in the place of s.id, and run the subquery. If it produces no rows, that student is added to the results. Move onto the next student

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen just refreshed to see your comment; noticed right after I posted and fixed, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need the cources in the query:

```
SELECT s.id    AS studentId,
       s.name  AS studentName,
FROM all_students     AS s
LEFT JOIN courses_students AS cs ON s.id = cs.student_id
GROUP BY s.id
HAVING COUNT(cs.student_id) = 0
```

So we are grouping by the student, but the count of the matching course is 0. I.e. all the values are NULL (by virtue of the `LEFT JOIN`).